# Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 not working with Network Card 82579

Tags: networking, drivers, intel

I was running a 16 Version and suddenly my HDD died. I moved to a 22.04 ubuntu version and the network card is not being recognized, is being showed as Unclaimed. I tried to download Intel's drivers but it seems that there is something with the kernel version or any other stuff, I have several errors and warnings. I also tried with other versions of the same driver and nothing.

Modprobe e1000e command returns nothing.

Any ideas?

```
lshw -C network     
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e1b00000-e1b1ffff memory:e1b80000-e1b80fff ioport:4080(size=32)


dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe e1000e` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks your replies. I just edited my first posts with the info requested.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: [0.840887] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[0.840889] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[0.841251] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 0.978811] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[ 1.089006] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) d4:be:d9:94:3e:b8
[ 1.089010] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[ 1.089059] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: E041FF-0FF[1.342950] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0

Comment: You have an interface eno1. Does Network Manager see a *Wired Connection 1* when you click the icon? Are there any clues here? `sudo dmesg | grep eno1`

Comment: there is nothing on the dmesg, besides the line that I posted before. Network Manager of the visual interface doesn't show any ethernet connection. I added an external network card (Realtek chip) and works, but the onboard (Intel) still showing as UNCLAIMED.

Comment: The time stamps show that the driver loaded and an interface was created early in the boot process. The fact that it shows as Unclaimed later suggests that later, for reasons we don't yet understand, it drops out. Let's see what the PCI bus is doing: `sudo dmesg | grep 19.0`

Comment: It's working now. The cable was unplugged and and soon as I plugged the interface start to show on the GUI network manager. I rebooted the ubuntu and stop working again. Only different the network calbe was plugged. dmesg | grep e1000e
[    0.820922] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.820926] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.821767] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.826347] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3

Comment: It seems that is a bug on kernels after version 5.10.35. [link]https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213481#c2